# Power BI publish to web with a free trial account

Tags: powerbi, publish

I have a power bi free pro trial account with a zohomail (so I don't own the domain). I was trying to publish a report to web but it's giving me this message : "Contact your admin to enable embed code creation" because I don't have admin portal tenant settings. I am not working for an organization, my power bi account is created with a zohomail so I don't know what to do. How can I be the admin for my account if I don't own the domain server? I am really confused. I hope it can be fixed because I need to publish the report to web as I need to share the link with someone who doesn't have a power bi account.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Power BI requires a school or work e-mail address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/service-self-service-signup-for-power-bi#supported-email-addresses). You can trick it with some less known e-mail provider, but as you can see, you can't really use it in its full strength. You have no other choice, but to sign up with a real work e-mail address. It is required, because there are administrative tasks (e.g. [allowing users to generate publish to web codes](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-publish-to-web-default-is-changing-and-it-affects-who-can-create-public-embed-codes/)), which now can be performed only by the owners of this "zohomail" domain.